# excel 2016 vba non-volatile user defined function recalculating unexpected

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am working with two structured table on two worksheets in one workbook.

I am using my UDF in SheetA which takes 3 arguments as string.

The first argument is ID column, the second argument is the first 8 characters on its column header cell, the third argument is the last 8 characters on its column header cell.

The UDF is applied to many other similar cells. The columns will be expanded as time pass by. ID and header cells are all static value. They are not derived from other cells.

The UDF will search TableB by "Application.Match" and draw values from matching rows and columns. If everything is valid, it will return appropriate results.

SheetA: TableA

| ID | 04/07/21 - 10/07/21 | 11/07/21 - 17/07/21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8)) | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21,8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8)) |
| AABBCC | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[04/07/21 - 10/07/21]],8)) | =UDF(TableA:[@[ID]:[ID]],LEFT(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21,8),Right(TableA[[#Headers],[11/07/21 - 17/07/21]],8)) |

SheetB: TableB

| Date | 123456 | AABBCC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/21 | 5.0 | -- |
| 05/07/21 | -- | 7.5 |
| 06/07/21 | -- | 7.5 |
| 07/07/21 | 8 | -- |
| 08/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 09/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 10/07/21 | -- | -- |
| 11/07/21 | -- | -- |

**My problem is that my UDF is causing time consuming calculation whenever I edit the tables (i.e. volatile) even I'm not editing those three arguments/related cells. Also, UDF recalculate whenever I collapse/expand grouped table columns. I would like to make the UDF recalculate only (when one of the arguments changes) or (if the values in "SumRange" changes). The result should behave somewhat like an index/match formula, when the matching range is updated.**

Here shows the UDF:

```
Function UDF(ID As String, Date1 As String, Date2 As String) As Variant
    TargetTable = "TableB"
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetB")

    With WS1
        matchCol = Application.Match(ID, .ListObjects(TargetTable).HeaderRowRange, 0)
        If IsError(matchCol) Then
            UDF = "ID not found"
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        matchRow1 = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(Date1)), .ListObjects(TargetTable).ListColumns("Date").Range, 0)
        matchRow2 = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(Date2)), .ListObjects(TargetTable).ListColumns("Date").Range, 0)
        
        Set SumRange = .Range(.Cells(matchRow1, matchCol), .Cells(matchRow2, matchCol))
        
        Arr = SumRange.Value
        For Each cel In Arr
            If Len(Trim(cel)) > 0 Then
                UDF = Application.Sum(SumRange)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
    
    UDF = ""
End Function
```

Comment: MRR, when you edit a cell any function that references that cell will recalculate volatile or not. From your description your function references the tables via Match and/or SumRange. Thus to avoid recalculation while editing tables you'll have to manually turn off recalculation.  HTH

Comment: Can you explain how match /sum react to recalculation? As far as I know, UDF only takes 3 arguments and UDF will only recalculate if any of the 3 argument changes. Is that right?

Comment: MMR, you are correct. I misspoke Charles explained it correctly below.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate your problem.

If I change a value in TableB the UDF does NOT recalculate (because it is not volatile and nothing in the UDF argument list has changed).
If I change something in Table A the UDF recalculates because all its fields are either formulas or referenced by the UDF.